# nullpointerexception in a for and if statement

Tags: java, android

I want to find 'elements in an array wjoined' which are not included in an array cjoined.
I cannot find what is wrong. Please help me. Following is my code. LogCat says 'Caused by:java.lang.NullPointerException'.

```
for (int x = 0; x < wjoined.length; x++)
{
    int count1 = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y < cjoined.length; y++)
    {
        if (wjoined[x].equals(cjoined[y]) )
        {
            count1++;
        }
    }
    if (count1 == 0){
        String sql = "INSERT INTO ErrorCausingFactor (errorcausingelement)"+"VALUE('"+wjoined[x] +"')";
        db.execSQL(sql);
    }
}
```

This is my logcat.

> 08-30 13:34:02.618: W/dalvikvm(1150): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x40014760) 08-30 13:34:02.628:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1150): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 08-30 13:34:02.628:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1150): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
>   activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.demo.testdemo/com.demo.testdemo.NextActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 08-30 13:34:02.628:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1150):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1748)
>   08-30 13:34:02.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1764)
>   08-30 13:34:02.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:122) 08-30
>   13:34:02.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1002)
>   08-30 13:34:02.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 08-30
>   13:34:02.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132) 08-30 13:34:02.628:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1150):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025) 08-30
>   13:34:02.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 08-30
>   13:34:02.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491) 08-30 13:34:02.628:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1150):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
>   08-30 13:34:02.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599) 08-30
>   13:34:02.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 08-30 13:34:02.628:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1150): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   08-30 13:34:02.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):   at
>   com.demo.testdemo.NextActivity.onCreate(NextActivity.java:157) 08-30
>   13:34:02.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
>   08-30 13:34:02.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1712)
>   08-30 13:34:02.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1150):   ... 11 more

Comment: Where do you get the exception? You can find it in the stacktrace.

Comment: At what line is the error given?

Comment: Have you set db to be an instance of something?

Comment: cjoined and wjoined do not have same length.

Comment: @user2733182 That shouldn't matter much. At what line did the nullpointerexception occur? What is `null`?

Comment: Well, either you have NULL values in your or you didn't initialize db properly.

Comment: A NPE is very easy to track down. The stack trace tells you exactly in which line it happens and then it is usually easy to find out which variable is `null`.

Comment: From your code one of following might be null : `wjoined, cjoined, wjoined[x]`. Add checks for null before using above objects.

Comment: or 'db' is null (or the db.execSql() call throws a NPE

Comment: how did this question get through review unharmed? :)

Comment: The problem is at this line:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 08-30 13:34:02.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1150): at com.demo.testdemo.NextActivity.onCreate(NextActivity.java:157)

Comment: Btw, you should ask a question. Just adding code and typing "help me" is not a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your locat should give you more details than just the exception, there will also be a stacktrace that should give you an indication on which line the NPE occured.

In your code I can see 3 possible locations to have an NPE being thrown:

1. In case wJoined is null then you will get an NPE thrown at the line number of your first for statement
2. In case cJoined is null then you will get an NPE thrown at the line number of your second for loop
3. if your database object db is null then you will get an NPE where you execute the insert statement.

Just inspect your stacktrace:

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 08-30 13:34:02.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1150): at com.demo.testdemo.NextActivity.onCreate(NextActivity.java:157)

EDIT: 4. is wJoined[x] is null this also raises an NPE as indicated by Roddy the frozen peas :-)

So it is on line 157 where the error occurs

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you see an Exception in the log it states the exact line where the error occurs. You should look into that. Not knowing the line i suspect either `wjoined`, `cjoined` or `db` is `null`

EDIT: seeing your log the error is on line 157 of NextActivity.java. See what that is and you probably know what's wrong

Comment: Or `wjoined[x]` could be null as well.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the values are `null`. Try this:

```
if (wjoined != null)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < wjoined.length; x++)
    {
        int count1 = 0;
        if (cjoined != null && wjoined[x] != null)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < cjoined.length; y++)
            {
                if (cjoined[y] != null)
                {
                    if (wjoined[x].equals(cjoined[y]) )
                    {
                        count1++;
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("cjoined[y]" is null at: " + y);
                }
            }
            if (count1 == 0){
                String sql = "INSERT INTO ErrorCausingFactor (errorcausingelement)"+"VALUE('"+wjoined[x] +"')";
                if (db != null)
                    db.execSQL(sql);
                else
                    System.out.println("db is null!");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("cjoined or wjoined[x] at x: " + x + " is null!");
        }
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("wjoined is null!");
}
```

Comment: And if `wjoined[x]` is null?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Edited accordingly. Thank you.